# Swagger UI does not react to form data elements

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger

In my aspnet core 3.1 project I have method to upload image also save another fields as well. I am using [FromForm] attribute for this. In postman everything works perfect but in swagger it does not react to anything if I press execute.

My Dto class looks like:

```
public class ImageUpdateDto
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }
    public IFormFile Image { get; set; }
}
```

My controller looks like:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
    [Consumes("multipart/form-data")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Unit>> Create([FromForm]ImageUpdateDto partner) =>
        Ok(await Mediator.Send(new Create.CreatePartnerCommand {Data = partner }));
```

Swagger screen:

[image: swagger]

Postman screen:

[image: postman]

P.S. I am using NSwag AspNet.Core and found also [same issue as mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58934503/swagger-ui-execute-button-not-working-when-file-is-uploading)

Comment: So you mean you cannot debug to the Create Action?I test with the code `[HttpPost("Create")]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized)]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
        [Consumes("multipart/form-data")]
        public IActionResult Create([FromForm]ImageUpdateDto partner) {
            return Ok();
        }`,and I can get partner,and return successfully.I use Swashbuckle.AspNetCore v5.5.1

Comment: yes I can not debug it. I am using nswag aspnet.core package 13.5 version

Comment: I test with nswag 13.7,and it works.

Comment: @YiyiYou perfect it seems it was bug in 13.5 now it is working in 13.7 fine